# How is the problem, {⟨G⟩|G has no triangle} in Logspace?

Tags: graphs, turing-machines, space-complexity

I read this problem as a part of my course curriculum, in my professor's notes. I am not able to understand about the standard solution, that if I list all the possible triplets of vertices as 3-tuples in the tape, then how come my solution is limited to log-space?

As far as my understanding, listing all the 3-tuples in the tape would need $\binom{n}{3}$ combinations, and hence, $O(n^3)$ space.

I am not able to find the flaw in my understanding, grateful ever for the hint.

P.S. This reference is from our course slide:

> Let $L$ be the language $\{⟨G⟩ \: | \: G\text{ has no triangle}\}$. Then $L$ can be recognized in log-space as follows: On the work tape, the machine $M$ can write all 3-tuples of the vertices of $G$. For each tuple written, the machine checks if there is a triangle passing through those vertices. If all tests fail, then $M$ accepts, otherwise $M$ rejects. The space used by $M$ is enough to store three vertex identifiers, therefore $L$ is in log-space.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to **first** write **all** 3-tuples and **then** check, for each of them, whether it induces a triangle.

You can just enumerate the 3-tuples **one at a time** and reject as soon as you find one that induces a triangle. If you reach past the last 3-tuple then the graph contains no triangle and you can accept.

Comment: So we need to choose a 3-tuple non deterministically right?

Comment: There is no need to use nondeterminism. Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $G$ and suppose that they are indexed from $0$. A 3-tuple is just 3 integers $a,b,c$. Initially  $a=b=c=0$. To generate the next 3-tuple simply increment $c$ by one, if it is equal to $n$ set it to 0 and increment $b$ by one. If $b$ is equal to $n$, set it to 0 and increment $a$ by one. If $a$ is equal to $n$ you are done enumerating all 3-tuples.

For each tuple that you generate in this way, check whether it induces a triangle. If so, reject. If it doesn't, move to the next tuple. If you reach the end, accept.

Comment: Thankyou, I got it!!

Answer (score 19):

```
FOR x := 1 TO n DO
    FOR y := 1 TO n DO
        FOR z := 1 TO n DO
            IF E(x,y) && E(y,z) && E(z,x) THEN REJECT
ACCEPT
```

Each of the variables `x`, `y` and `z` requires $\Theta(\log \texttt{n})$ bits to store an integer between $1$ and $\texttt{n}$.